# ¿Cómo hago una RegExr que no permita ningún tipo de caracteres especiales?

Tags: java, regex, validación, java-8, input

Necesito ayuda sobre como hacer una regExr que no permita caracteres especiales y a su vez tampoco permita '/' al inicio, al final, ni 2 '/' consecutivas.

para la condición de las '/' use esta:

```
"^(?!\\/)(?:(?!\\/\\/).)*(?<!\\/)$"
```

Pero después de probar, no se cual sirva para que no permita caracteres especiales y que cumpla la condición anterior a la vez

> **tipos de entrada válidos**

- rad/1235 -> no lanza excepción
- 12345612 -> no lanza excepción
- asduij42as -> no lanza excepción

> **tipos de entada no válidos**

- /rad1235
- rad.123
- rad1235/
- rad1235_
- rád1235
- rad1//235_
- rad1/235

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo probar con la siguiente expresion regular:

```
^([a-z0-9]+(\/{1}[a-z0-9]+)*)+(?!([\/]{2}))$
```

Como veras tiene un negative lookeahead para asegurarse que no contenga doble `/` y un grupo que se encarga del resto de la expresion, en la que indicamos que puede tener uno o mas caracteres alfaumericos seguido de una seccion de un `/` seguido de mas por lo menos un caracter alfanumerico.

[image: Maquina de estados de la expresion regular]

Esta expresion regular funcionara en varios lenguajes de programacion, si deseas que solo funcione ne Java puedes usar [clases de carateres POSIX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

```
^(\p{Alnum}+(\/{1}\p{Alnum}+)*)+(?!([\/]{2}))$
```